# Java animation:can't see anything

Tags: java, animation

I am doing animation with Java and I'm using NetBeans. My applet has started but I don't see anything in the applet viewer? Can anybody see any problem with my code and this is my first programming course as U can see =)! Thanks for advance!!

Problem.1  Do animation with 10 gif pictures by using MediaTracker,addImage and thread.sleep.

(Code)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Animaatio extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    Image images[] = null;
    MediaTracker tracker  = null;
    Thread animaatio;
    Graphics g;

    @Override
    public void init()
    { 
            tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
            images = new Image[10];
            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {
          images[i] = getImage( getCodeBase(),"T" + (i+1) + ".gif"); 
                tracker.addImage(images[i],0);  
            }
            try{

    tracker.waitForAll();

}catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
    @Override
public void start() {
        if (animaatio == null) {
            animaatio = new Thread(this);
            animaatio.start();
      }
}

    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawImage(images[10], 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }                               
            catch (InterruptedException e)  {}
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Applets reached their end of life years ago.  Why are people still teaching this?

Comment: You've already asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090075/needing-java-help-in-animation). This is almost an exact duplicate. Please refrain from doing that and delete this question ASAP.